# Is it possible to assign this serialNumber to a variable in python?

Tags: python, ssl

```
import ssl, socket

hostname = '    '
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
with ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=hostname) as s:
    s.connect((hostname, 443))
    cert = s.getpeercert()

subject = dict(x[0] for x in cert['subject'])
issued_to = subject['commonName']

issuer = dict(x[0] for x in cert['issuer'])
issued_by = issuer['commonName']

serialNumber = dict(x[0] for x in cert['serialNumber'])


print(cert)
print(issued_to) 
print(issued_by)
```

s153152@MB20OXDHQ60774 Documents % python3 test3.py
{'subject': ((('countryName', 'US'),), (('stateOrProvinceName', 'California'),), (('localityName', 'Eureka'),), (('organizationName', 'departmentName'),), (('organizationalUnitName', 'hostname1'),), (('commonName', 'hostname.ca.gov'),)), 'issuer': ((('domainComponent', 'gov'),), (('domainComponent', 'ca'),), (('domainComponent', 'dot'),), (('domainComponent', 'ct'),), (('commonName', '-CA'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '646ss8AA2A000100000F0C', 'notBefore': 'Apr  9 21:26:20 2020 GMT', 'notAfter': 'Dec 28 19:45:58 2021 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'hostname.ca.gov'), ('DNS', ''), ('DNS', 'hostname'), ('DNS', 'hostname.ca.gov'), ('DNS', 'hostname.ca.gov')), 'caIssuers': ('ldap:///CN=-CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=ca,DC=gov?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('ldap:///CN=-CA(1),CN=,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=ca,DC=gov?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint',)}.ca.gov
output1
s153152@MB20OXDHQ60774 Documents %

want this output
'serialNumber': '6468AA2A000100000F0C'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
serialNumber = dict(x[0] for x in cert['serialNumber'])
```

The serial number is a single value, not a dict. Therefore

```
serialNumber = cert['serialNumber']
```